# does 'bad-ass data preparer' mean bad data or good data?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I read that's in an article

> 'having a reputation as a *bad-ass data  preparer*  wouldn't be the
>   worst thing in the world.

'
look at the link below, it is line 18 or you can find it on line 5 after picture

[enter link description here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/03/5-things-know-about-machine-learning.html)

Comment: You need to add references. The only hits for "a badass data" and "a bad-ass data" I've found on the internet use 'data' attributively (data scientist, data analyst...). This would appear to be a nonce usage, and hence pronouncements on its intended meaning opinion-based. 'Bad-ass' has conflicting definitions (all slang, I believe) you can look up for yourself.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, as well as a link to the quote and more of it. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Questions not including reasonable research may be closed. Questions where one has to guess at what the author/speaker intended are also off-topic.

Comment: look here, it is line 18  or you can find it on line 5 after picture                                              
             https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/03/5-things-know-about-machine-learning.html

Answer (score 1):

The full phrase you are quoting is:

> having a reputation as a bad-ass data preparer wouldn't be the worst thing in the world

The phrase "bad-ass" is used to modify "data preparer". This section of the article is talking about how data preparation is an important part of machine learning.

["Bad ass" is defined](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/badass), when used as an adjective not referring to a person, as:

> distinctively tough or powerful; so exceptional as to be intimidating.

So, the article is encouraging one to become exceptional, to the point of intimidating others with their skills, at being a data preparer. Doing this will help one advance their career in machine learning.

Comment: But this _**is**_ referring to a person, so the definition you omit is also a possibility.

Comment: @Edwin No, it's not referring to a person. It's referring to a role. "Bob is a bad-ass" is different than "Bob is a bad-ass data preparer". The first refers to a person, the second modifies the position or role.

Comment: It comes after '... being determined to be the very best data preparation professional around is a pretty good goal.' Here, 'very best' is obviously ranking the person against others; bad-ass defaults pragmatically to describing what sort of a data preparer the person is. It is not a classifier of either data (bad-ass data!?) and even if you stretch probabilities to say it could classify 'data preparer', these are still people. And you'd need to disambiguate with commas (a bad-ass-data-preparer).

Comment: @Edwin Are you even reading the same words I am? This is correct. Data preparer is not a person. If you have a better answer, please post it and back it up the way that I have, using knowledge of English, the context of the article, and a dictionary.

Comment: You are confusing syntactic and semantic reference. Whatever words 'bad-ass' is modifying in the sentence, the referent is ultimately the person involved, and hence the other sense given by UD << 1.
(of a person) difficult to deal with; mean-tempered; touchy >> also comes into play here. / My response was to close-vote because OP didn't add reasonable references. Easily found (now we know what the question actually is) in a dictionary.

Comment: @Edwin I don't agree that is correct - there's a difference between modifying a particular person and a role that a person may have. Much like words like "senior" modify roles and not people. But let's say it was. In the context of the article, why would someone be encouraged to be a "difficult to deal with data preparer"? That makes no sense.

Comment: The word is labelled 'informal' in the dictionaries I've checked (I'll add that some don't include the 'of a person' caveat). Informal writing is usually not to the more exact standards of more formal writing. That aside, here, I'd certainly expect the sense you give. But the logic you use to arrive at it being the only possible choice is flawed.

Comment: @Edwin When I get to a computer, I can edit in the alternative definition. However, I don't know how anyone can reach the conclusion that the definition of "difficult to deal with, mean-tempered, touchy" can be correct in the context of the article. Context eliminates it as a correct answer. And one when you eliminate one of two answers, the one that remains is correct.

Comment: I agree. But you're neatly shifting away from the problem in your answer, which remains identified by 'You are confusing syntactic and semantic reference. Whatever words 'bad-ass' is modifying in the sentence, the referent is ultimately the person involved, and hence the other sense given by UD << 1. (of a person) difficult to deal with; mean-tempered; touchy >> also comes into play here. You need to state the alternative definition and discount it for the right reason. (Though OP should have done this themself on ELU.)

Comment: @Edwin Again, I don't understand that claim. Data preparer is not a person. I don't agree they the referent is a person.

Comment: Two things: 1) I disagree with the definition in the link '(of a person) difficult to deal with; mean-tempered; touchy.'. I've never heard it used that way of anything. But let's set that aside and assume it's true (experience is always limited) 2) the wording of part 2 definition _does not exclude_ people.  Otherwise it would say '(not of a person)'.

Comment: 'Jones is a bad-ass data preparer.' We are speaking of a human (even though we are also specifying his occupation). A human referent. // '... this bad ass program' [taken from the internet]. We are not speaking of a human.